# Cocoapods inside iOS framework not working

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a framework with some features of my App, which depends on Cocoapods for its dependencies.

The framework is compiling OK, but when added into another project, it crashes with this trace

```
    Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BA3917FD-FCF1-491B-90AF-86AFDCD7FF80/BMNPoC.app/Frameworks/myframework.framework/myframework
  Reason: image not found
```

When searching on product folder I see my framework and the pod framework with AFNetworking in this case (so 3 separated frameworks). I guess those frameworks aren't being embed into MyFramework. How can I achieve this? Here's a link to a demo project https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9dbx9xy61twcoa/MyFramework.zip?dl=0

Comment: How did you add the framework into your project?

Comment: I attach the framework to the project and check it's referenced in "linked frameworks and libraries" and in "embedded binaries"